# Time Series Plot in R - Line Graph

Tags: r, plot, graph

I have an excel file with 5 Categories and I want to plot the category on the Y-Axis, and the Month of the year on the X-axis with the values of the matrix being the values.

The excel sheet is set up like this

Category | January | March | April

Cat.   1 |   val.  |  val  |  val.
Cat.   2 |.  val   |  val  |  val

etc

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach. You have to reshape your data to long format and then plot it. Here an approach using `ggplot2` and `tidyverse` functions. I have used dummy data similar to yours. Here the code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Category=paste0('Cat.',1:5),
                 January=runif(5,10,20),
                 March=runif(5,20,30),
                 April=runif(5,30,40),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot and data reshape
df %>% pivot_longer(-Category) %>%
  mutate(name=factor(name,levels = unique(name),ordered = T)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=name,y=value,group=Category,color=Category))+
  geom_line(size=1)+
  theme_bw()+
  xlab('Month')
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this in `base R` easily with `matplot`

```
matplot(t(df[-1]), type = 'l', xlab = "", xaxt = 'n', col = seq_len(nrow(df)))
legend("topright", inset = .05, legend = df$Category, pch = 1, 
          col = seq_len(nrow(df)), horiz = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Category = c("Cat.1", "Cat.2", "Cat.3", "Cat.4", 
"Cat.5"), January = c(19.8101808479987, 12.8288395586424, 18.4788214950822, 
10.8223923086189, 18.8645875058137), March = c(24.7193073085509, 
21.0910096345469, 23.3327798452228, 28.3741656923667, 22.76849841699
), April = c(35.8703514141962, 38.3673226973042, 30.7115402398631, 
37.0277874334715, 36.9882453721948)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: what if I didn't want to hard code in all the values like you did here?

Comment: @j_nj I didn't hard coded the values.  It is just `dput(df)` gives the structure of the data